# Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to obtain the maximum time consumed by a stored procedure in my DB. I obtained a sample query from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701(v=sql.110).aspx) to obtain the same using sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats. The same is posted below. Whenever I try to execute this query I get the error as

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats'.

Can you please let me know where I might probably be going wrong?

Below is the query used. No changes made.

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name',
       d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,
       d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
       d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

EDIT: Sorry for the blunder. Server is 2005.

Comment: Check compatible level. BTW `sys` schema always is public

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: The error doesn't seems to be any permission issue. More like it is compatibility issue.

Comment: The database compatibility level does *not* affect the visibility of DMVs. The only way to get this error is if you're not running SQL Server 2008 or higher.

Comment: And the result of `print @@version` is...